# UnHandled Exception while dynamically adding TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, unhandled-exception

I am trying to dynamically add textbox onclick of button. Below is my code. I am able to add one textbox, but while adding next textbox after completing all code `UnHandled exception` is thrown. I don't know from where it is being thrown.

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);

            controlidlist = (List<string>)ViewState["controlidlist"];
            if(controlidlist != null)
            {
                foreach (string Id in controlidlist)
                {
                    i++;
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = Id;
                    System.Web.UI.LiteralControl lineBreak = new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl();
                    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(tb);
                    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                controlidlist = new List<string>();
            }

        }
```

ButtonClick Event:

```
protected void Button_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                     
            try
            {
                i++;
                TextBox tB = new TextBox();
                tB.ID = "textBox_" + i;


                System.Web.UI.LiteralControl lineBreak = new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("<br>");
                UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(tb);
                UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
                ViewState["controlidlist"] = controlidlist;
                controlidlist.Add(tb.ID);
                UpdatePanel1.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { }

        }
```

After completely executing above code below exception is thrown in Global.asax.

Error:

> {"Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown."}

global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError() as HttpUnhandledException;
        if (exception != null && exception.InnerException is ProductNotFoundException)
        {

        }
    }
```

**This may be simple, but I am very new to this**

Comment: I would first try adding a line inside your button_click1 catch like:  string s = string.Format("Error: {0}, Additional Info: {1}", ex.message, ex.innermessage);  Then, put a break on this line, as well as a break in the first code line inside your try. And review your code in debug mode.

Comment: @nocturns, Exception not thrown in ButtonClick method, after fully executing ButtonClick method, its calling Application_Error with UnHandled Exception.

Comment: If you add the catch code above, you'll have an opportunity to examine things before the code completes.

Comment: Looking at your code, you have the literal initialized in your button_click1 but not in your LoadViewState. If the problem is your literal, you can use:  UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); You'll have to be running in Full Trust. Other than that, I was wondering about your variable i. (i.e., the possibility of duplicate id's)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for adding dynamic `TextBox` with line break:

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.ID = "textBox_" + i;
ViewState["controlidlist"] = controlidlist;
controlidlist.Add(tb.ID);
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(t);
Literal lit = new Literal() { Mode=LiteralMode.PassThrough, Text="<br/>" };
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Hope it will solves your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Checking with ViewState["controlidlist"] is not required? Its not working, always showing only one button